# Suppose that $f(x)^2 = 2\int^x_0{f(t)dt}$, for all $x ≥ 0$. Show that $f(x) = x$ for all $x≥0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, with $f(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$. Suppose that

$f(x)^2 = 2\int^x_0{f(t)dt}$, for all $x ≥ 0$
. Show that $f(x) = x$ for all $x≥0$

I just learnt this material and I am struggling but I think I have the right approach: One way to show functions are the same is to show they both have the same antiderivative. I know I am meant to use that here, I am struggling to see how.

Comment: How about taking the derivative of both sides of the equation given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, which is $F'(x)=f(x)$

Differentiate both sides and use $f(x)>0$:

$2f(x)f'(x)=2f(x)$

$f'(x)=1$

so $f(x)=x+C$

Now if you put $x=0$ in the original equation you get $f(0)^2=2\int_0^0f(t)dt=0$ so $f(0)=0$, which gives $C=0$

Comment: How do you know $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: @Logan Clark: The gory details: RHS of the original equation is differentiable, so the LHS $f(x)^2$ is differentiable. And $f(x)>0$ gives $f(x)=\sqrt{f(x)^2}$ which is differentiable for $x>0$, as composition of two differentiable functions. We solve and find $f(x)=x+C$ for $x>0$ and we extend $f$ to cover $x=0$ by continuity :)

Comment: Just making sure I got it out of you, my professor took points off of my solution to this problem for just that reason. ;)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Because of the rush of getting the solution done in time, sometimes quality suffers.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous, then $F(x)=2\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is differentiable with $F'(x)=2f(x)$.

If $F(x)=f^2(x)$, then $F'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$.

Hence, we see that $2f(x)f'(x)=2f(x)$ implies that either $f(x)=0$ or $f'(x)=1$.

But $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, so we must have $f'(x)=1$, whereby we see that $f(x)=x+C$.

Finally, since $f(0)=0$, $C=0$ and therefore $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Hint: Don't try to understand the voting behaviour on MSE (+1)

Comment: @tired That's a good idea.  It's beyond my limited capacity to understand.